# How do I stop errors with TOP lookup from a previous record in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access query I've built that produces three fields:

`Rank` - 1, 2, 3 4 etc (sorted in descending order)

`ID1` - an identifier of a person, with duplicates

`ID2` - an identifer of a second person, with duplicates

From this query I want to write a second query that displays both the first two fields and then creates a third field that looks for the previous `ID2` of the current `ID1` record.

Using SQL cobbled from a few places I was pretty successful with this:

```
SELECT ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank, ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1, (SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank) AS PRIOR_ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small;
```

However, if the ID1 record is the first instance in the list then I get a blank as there is no previous record to lookup. Instead of the blank I want to record a value of 1500.

So I thought it was a case of a simple IIf statement as follows:

```
SELECT ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank, ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1, IIf((SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank)<>"",(SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank),1500) AS PRIOR_ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small;
```

However, whilst this now inserts the 1500 correctly, the other records for the third field come back as errors. I'm sure it's a simple fix but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for coming back so quickly. `ISNULL`returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` so it needed an `IIf` statement but that did the trick!

Here's the final code:

```
SELECT ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank, ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1, IIf(ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank)),1500,(SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank)) AS PRIOR_ID2
FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to follow your query, especially without sample data. But I think you might just need a `ISNULL` function:

```
    SELECT ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank, ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1, 
     ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1, Dupe.ID2
      FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small as Dupe
      WHERE Dupe.ID1 = ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.ID1
      AND Dupe.Rank < ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small.Rank),1500) AS PRIOR_ID2
      FROM ELO_ranked_lookup_atp_small;
```